# Tinymce not showing in the second page of a Data Tables

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, datatables, tinymce-5

I've a table like the following and I'm using DataTable:

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped mb-0" id="datatable-persone-telefonate">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>1</th>
            <th>2</th>
            <th>3</th>
            <th>4</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr data-item-id="">
            <td data-sort="2021-04-07">1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
            <td align="right" class="actions" width="10%">
            <a class="modal-basic" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#modalPersoneTelefonateM9" href="#"><i class="fas fa-edit" title="Modifica"></i></a>

<!-- Inizio modifica telefonate -->
<div class="modal" data-focus="false" id="modalPersoneTelefonateM9" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
        <form id="frmPersoneTelefonateM9" action="" class="form-horizontal" method="post" name="frmPersoneTelefonateM9">
            <input id="persona_telefonata_id_m9" name="persona_telefonata_id_m9" type="hidden" value="9" />
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header alert-primary">
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Modifica la telefonata</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="form-group row pb-3">
                        <label class="col-sm-3 control-label" for="persona_telefonata_descrizione_m9">Descrizione <span class="required">*</span></label>
                        <div class="col-sm-9">
                            <textarea class="form-control" id="persona_telefonata_descrizione_m9" name="persona_telefonata_descrizione_m9" required rows="10"><p>CCC</p></textarea>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="submit" class="mb-1 mt-1 mr-1 btn btn-primary" id="btnPersoneTelefonateM9">Modifica</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
</div>

<script>
    $("#frmPersoneTelefonateM9").validate({
        submitHandler: function(form) {
            var persona_attiva_id = $.cookie("persona_attiva_id");
            var persona_telefonata_id_m = $('#persona_telefonata_id_m9').val();
            var persona_telefonata_descrizione_m = tinymce.get("persona_telefonata_descrizione_m9").getContent();
                        
            var formData = new FormData();
            formData.append('am', '01');
            formData.append('persona_attiva_id', persona_attiva_id);
            formData.append('persona_telefonata_id', persona_telefonata_id_m);
            formData.append('persona_telefonata_descrizione', persona_telefonata_descrizione_m);
            
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                async: false,
                url: "apps/persone-telefonate-am.php",
                data: formData,
                cache: false,
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
                success: function(data) {
                    $('#modalPersoneTelefonateM9').modal('hide');
                    var notice = new PNotify({
                        title: 'Successo!',
                        text: 'Telefonata modificata. Attendi per favore...',
                        type: 'success',
                        addclass: 'notification-primary click-2-close',
                        //icon: 'fa fa-2x fa-shopping-cart',
                        hide: true,
                        delay: 2500,
                        mouse_reset: true,
                        buttons: {
                            closer: true,
                            sticker: false
                        });
                        setTimeout(
                            function() {
                                parent.location.reload();
                            }, 2500
                        );
                    },
                    error: function() {
                        alert("Errore nella modifica della telefonata");
                        $('#modalPersoneTelefonateM9').modal('hide');
                    }
                });
                return false;
            }
        });
        </script>
        <!-- Fine modifica telefonate -->
    </td>
</tr>
...
...
</tbody>
</table>
```

The DataTable is set with a pagination of 10 records. When I go to the second page of the DataTable the textareas don't show TinyMCE. Instead, the space where TinyMCE should appear is blank and no more appears. If I go back to the first page, the problem is still there. If I call the modal only on the first page everything works fine.

Can you help me?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I can't get this from the snippets of code in your question, but every time when you dynamically load a page using AJAX, you have to reactivate TinyMCE for de newly loaded text areas.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. How should I do to reactivate TinyMCE? Is there a way? Thank you so much

Comment: See: https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/quick-start/ I think `tinymce.init(<...>).` will probably work.

Comment: Yes, thanks! It works! A cup of coffee for you ;-)